# What washer dryer do I need for this space?

Tags: dryer, installation, washing-machine, washer

I am planning to rent an apartment which has this picture where washer dryer should be installed.

Can I get some guidance on what kind of washer dryer do I need and how to install it. No one in my family is able to life a washer dryer from the curb - back problems. I haven't ever installed a washer/dryer before but I am willing to learn.

[image]
https://s3.amazonaws.com/Rently_dev/images/3285692/large

Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: None of us can lift a washer/dryer either. That's what appliance dollies are for.

Comment: At the least, measure the space and buy something smaller. From the looks of it, you may need to add a U-trap for the drain. Check for gas or electric outlets to support the requirements of the dryer.

Comment: @Harper I can lift a washer/dryer, I just don't want to right now.

Comment: @Tester101  that's funny.  I almost added that you could, due to the accident with the arc flash, but I didn't want to give away your secret identity!

Comment: @Glorfindel Thank you for bringing this closed-for-six-years question back to everyone’s attention on the front page. Truly your suggested edit of the image will tip the balance back in favor of re-opening this off-topic product recommendation question. NOT. Don’t edit junk. Especially don’t suggest edits on junk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some builders ( mostly in large city complexes) provide limited space or delete some of the utility hook-ups to save money on construction, forcing you to use more exotic washer/dryers.  You don't have that problem; all the usual utilities are there.

To the left we see hookups for a **common washing machine**.  You have hot and cold water supply spigots; a sanitary sewer drain for ejected water; and a 120V power outlet with GFCI in the outlet.

To the right we see hookups for an **electric dryer**.   A large 240V power receptacle, and a large diameter vent pipe for the moist air ejected by the dryer.  You really don't want moist air coming into your living space unless you like mold and water damage from water condensing on windows and running down and rotting out the window frames. The heat from the dryer is also ejected from the house, which is a shame in winter; the easiest way to recover that heat is to use a condensing dryer.

You might also have a gas line there for gas dryer, but if you do, it's out of shot.   Gas dryers absolutely require a vent pipe.

Since the dryer is not yet installed, you might want to see about clearing that pipe of lint as best you can.  Lint slows down air movement, can block the pipe, and can even start a fire.

---

To benefit other readers, what if some hookups are missing?  First,  you need power and drain, or you will not be washing clothes.

If there is no dryer vent pipe, you can obtain a **condensing dryer**.  This has an internal dehumidifier which pulls the water out of the air, dumping the water into the washer's drain pipe. It has some way of keeping the lint from clogging the dehumidifier fins.

If there's no hot water hookup, you can buy a **heating washer**.  This takes cold water only, and if you select "warm" or "hot, it heats the water with an internal heater.   This is much more reliable, because it positively heats the water instead of merely hoping what comes out of the hot-water spigot is actually hot. It works much better on front-load washers, since they have a great deal less water to heat.

If there is no 120V power outlet, some washer-dryer matched sets are made for the washer to get electricity from the dryer.

If the space is too narrow for separate washer/dryer, you can get **combo washer-dryers** in a single unit.  They also sell **stackable** washer and dryers, however these are always front-load washer.